# Missing output from assembly program on MacOS

Tags: assembly, output, nasm

Trying to run a simple program, written in nasm on my Macbook. Code below, I've removed all unnecessary pieces and simplified the code as much as possible.

**Problem**:

- when printing txt1, output is properly printed to stdout
- when printing txt2 (as in the code below), no output is produced, exit code is 0.

Code:

```
%define SYSCALL_EXIT  0x2000001
%define SYSCALL_WRITE 0x2000004
%define STDOUT 0x1

section .data
    txt1:  db "first line of text", 10, 0
    t1len: equ $-txt1

    txt2 db "second line of text", 10, 0
    t2len: equ $-txt2

section .text
    global _main

_main:
    call printText

    mov rax, SYSCALL_EXIT
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

printText:
    mov rax, SYSCALL_WRITE
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    mov rsi, txt2
    mov rdx, t2len
    syscall
    ret
```

Compiling:

```
nasm -f macho64 -o name2.o name2.asm
```

Linking:

```
gcc -o name2 name2.o -Wl,-no_pie
```

Also tried with *ld*:

```
ld -e _main -o name2 name2.o
```

Nasm version:

```
mac:asm-codes jabbson$ nasm -v
NASM version 2.13.02 compiled on Nov 30 2017
```

GCC version:

```
mac:asm-codes jabbson$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Reason for -Wl,-no_pie - without it i am getting an error:

```
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in printText from name2.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
```

ld version:

```
mac:asm-codes jabbson$ ld -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-305
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em (tvOS)
LTO support using: LLVM version 9.0.0, (clang-900.0.39.2) (static support for 21, runtime is 21)
TAPI support using: Apple TAPI version 900.0.15 (tapi-900.0.15)
```

Comment: Works for me. I have the exact same versions (High Sierra). NASM was from `brew` (same version as yours). When I use your command lines (ld and gcc didn't matter) I get the line `second line of text` printed out. You sure the code above is what you are using? Are you running the exact version you posted? running the right program?

Comment: Yes, the code is exact to the letter.

Comment: Actually I did some debugging and I see why the code is not printed. Program tried to lookup the string by wrong offset, i do not understand why yet.

Comment: [Offset problem - radare2 output](https://image.prntscr.com/image/MKP0kWOkSLeqqqF0A2n7Rw.png)

Comment: `mov rsi, txt2` moves the address of txt2 to RSI.

Comment: What happens if you add the directive `default rel` to the top of the assembly file and then replace `mov rsi, txt2` with `lea rsi, [txt2]` and then use GCC **without** the `-Wl,-no_pie` option

Comment: Then it suddenly works. Could you elaborate on this, because I do not quite understand why it didn't work before. Thanks, Michael.

Comment: I'm not sure why your version doesn't work. Your version works here. As for the changes I made - the code is now position independent which is the preferred default addressing for MacOS programs.

Comment: Maybe with your version you need to add `-static` to your GCC command line?

Comment: should i be using brewed version of gcc for that, Michael?

Comment: I was using the Apple Version of GCC/LD/G++. I only used the brew version of NASM.

Comment: Adding -static to my gcc command line produces following error:

ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o